# Why SHA-224 and SHA-256 use different initial values?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, hash-function

[Wikipedia - SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) says

> SHA-224 is identical to SHA-256, except that:
>
> - the initial variable values h0 through h7 are different, and
> - the output is constructed by omitting h7.

[RFC3874 - A 224-bit One-way Hash Function: SHA-224](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3874.txt) says

> The use of a different initial value ensures that a truncated SHA-256
>   message digest value cannot be mistaken for a SHA-224 message
>   digest value computed on the same data.

My questions:

1. Is the above quoted reason the only reason why SHA-224 and SHA-256 use different initial values?
2. Why is it important to make sure that a SHA-256 message digest value cannot be mistaken for a SHA-224 message digest value?
3. If we use the same initial values for both hash functions, will the security of either hash function worsen? If yes, how?

Comment: This is almost certainly a better fit on [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: At least question 2 seems to be off-topic here. After all, it is related to how people use computers and what is convenient for them; not really a TCS question.

Comment: Related question on Crypto.SE: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3946/using-sha-256-with-different-initial-hash-value

Answer (score 5):

1. This We called Domain Separation, when we use same algorithm for different output size.
2. Separation is necessary because if i found two messages which have hash value (SH256), differs only in last octet and then i can publish the hash value as first 7 octet showing i used SHA224. since i already have two messages colliding on SHA224 which i can use later for forgery attack.
   Using domain separation we can avoid such situation